# Why are Android Apps not as polished as iOS?

Tags: ios, user-interface

When I owned a iPhone, all the software seemed to be very polished(Visually). For example, the process to getting to menu's shorter etc. I own an s4 and the apps and the software does not seem to be as polished as iOS?

Both platforms are being developed by very intelligent programmers and creative people, so why is it that Android is not as polished?

Comment: what is polished?? you have windows transition and animation scale

Comment: They don't seeem to be as visually appealing

Comment: You can set the windows animation and transition animation scale

Comment: How can i do this? Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: @sameer That's a development option, to make it easier for app developers to test animations in their own apps. It's not intended for general use, and might make some apps behave oddly.

Comment: @DanHulme I know it is a developer option but will it cause any effect on app? I thought it is like aero animation scale in windows

Comment: @sameer As an example, say an app runs one animation and another when the first is supposed to finish. Scaling the animation length makes the first one finish late, and the second might start while the first is still running, causing a conflict. The more complex the animations are, the more likely that changing something will make them go wrong.

Comment: One man's polish is another man's unnecessary glitz.

Comment: I mean, I can see why Apple users tend to stick to their devices. Because they are in a way a lot simpler to use and almost apps "look better on the eyes". @Dan Hulme explained why that is probably the case... conventions, open source, hobbiest etc... But if Android really wants to kill the competition surely this is one area where it can improve? This is just my own opinion guys :)

Comment: This question was asked to find out some information and get user opinions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It really comes down to customer expectations. With iOS, Apple uses the built-in apps to set an expectation that apps will be "blingy", with all kinds of eye-catching animations. If you look at Android's built-in apps, they're not so eye-catching: animations are subtle (usually simple fades or fly-ins), they have a much cleaner, drier look, and they have very similar, familiar conventions about menus and transitions. This has set the expectation amongst Android users that app-specific bling is much less important than respecting the conventions of the platform and integrating well with other apps.

At the same time, the app ecosystem and the consumer market are very different on Android. Apple has a very large barrier to entry: you can't realistically develop iOS apps without buying a Mac, and a physical device, and paying a subscription to Apple. This means that for the most part, hobbyists and small developers are excluded from this market.

In contrast, the Android development tools are freely available and support Windows, Mac, and Linux; there's no subscription to be a developer; you can get onto Google Play for a small, one-off fee, or distribute apps outside of Google Play (on other app stores or independently).

For this reason, while Android still has all the big-name developers you find writing iOS apps, there's also a much larger number of small developers and hobbyists. Hobbyists are much less likely to add bling or visual design features to their apps, because they just want to develop something useful. There are a lot of incredibly well-written and useful hobbyist and open-source apps, but they're much less likely to add visual design varnish to them. As well as bringing down the average amount of varnish for an app, this also feeds back into the consumer expectation that Android apps don't need so much bling.